# disk space issues on Amazon Ubuntu?

Tags: permissions, php, mysql, disk-usage

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 server running on Amazon, it's a well seasoned instance that's been running for several years.  This is not a shared hosting system, the whole thing is ours.  We just started getting error messages relating to disk space, such as:

> Warning: session_start(): open(/var/lib/php5/sess_6q18snb4mk50dlige4vb8ch2r3, O_RDWR) failed: No space left on device (28)

and

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_370_0.MYI' (Errcode: 28)

when I check the file system, I get:

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      197G  165G   23G  89% /
udev            7.4G  8.0K  7.4G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.5G  176K  1.5G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /run/shm
```

Overall there's plenty of space left.  I don't see any partitions in particular trouble.  What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found that a 3rd party web app was managing it's own session files and failing garbage collection.  Once we deleted some very old folders of them, the issues disappeared.